# Is it possible to connect a JS WebSocket to a Python server?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, webserver

Is it possible to connect a JS WebSocket to a Python server or just to webservers? When it's possible - how?

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of options. Take a look at [`aiohttp` primer](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#websockets)

Answer (score 0):

I found https://socket.io/ to be quite easy.
Love it.